# VF PageBlockTable w/ Javascript and Conditional Behavior

Tags: javascript, salesforce, visualforce, force.com, salesforce-service-cloud

Hello StackOverflow Community,

I develop in Force.com and am strong in Visualforce and Apex. I am not strong in Javascript but tend to get by when necessary. On a recent project, I am struggling with something very basic and I figured SO was the best place to find help.

I utilize apex:pageblocktable(s) to drive "available actions" to the user. Basically the page loads, the system queries my external static "action" table and compares the data in the current record to the action table records. Upon completion, the user is presented with the result: available actions.

I am running into one problem. There are some actions that I cannot pass the ?id= as a parameter due to the user selecting a generic action. To solve this I need a simple IF CONDITION within my javascript formula. Below I have posted my code... Your thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

**CURRENT CODE:**

```
<apex:pageBlock mode="edit" title="Other Actions">
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!OtherActions}" var="action">
<apex:column>
<a href="javascript:sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null, 'https://na15.salesforce.com/apex/{!action.URL__c}?actionname={!action.Name}', true, null, null, null);">{!action.Name}</a>
</apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

**MY ATTEMPT:**

The code below works. However, for some reason the action selected by the user acts as though it is is always the last action in the list. For example, if three actions load and you select the 2nd. The system will behave as though you selected the 3rd action...always

```
<apex:pageBlock mode="edit" title="Other Actions">
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!OtherActions}" var="action">
<apex:column>
<a href="#" onclick="MyFunction();return false;">{!action.Name}</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function MyFunction() {
        if({!action.Name} == 'Test'){
        sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null , 'https://na15.salesforce.com/apex/{!action.URL__c}?id={!action.id}&actionname={!action.Name}', true, ' ', null, null);
        }
        else{
        sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null , 'https://na15.salesforce.com/apex/{!action.URL__c}?actionname={!action.Name}', true, ' ', null, null);
        }        
    }
</script>
</apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to pass the parameters to the Java functions. Here is the final VisualForce / Java Combo

**VF**

```
<apex:column >
<A HREF="#" onClick="openAction('{!action.External__c}', '{!action.ID}', '{!action.Name}', '{!action.URL__c}');return false">{!action.Name}</A>
</apex:column>
```

**java**

```
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    var TabID;
    var previousOnload = window.onload;       
    window.onload = function() {
    if (previousOnload) {
    previousOnload();
    }               
    setTimeout('setTabTitle()', '500');
    setTimeout('getTabID()', '500');
    }
    function setTabTitle() {
    sforce.console.setTabTitle('{!Member__c.Name}');
    }
    function getTabID() {
    sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(setTabID);
    }
    var setTabID = function setTabID(result) {
    TabID = result.id;
    }
    function openAction(external, id, name, url) {
        if(external == 'true'){
        sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(TabID, 'https://na15.salesforce.com/apex/' + url, true, ' ');
        }
        else{
        sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null, 'https://na15.salesforce.com/apex/' + url + '?id=' + id, true, ' ');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to write

```
if('{!action.Name}' == 'Test')
```

instead of

```
if({!action.Name} == 'Test')
```

The difference being the first one will compare two string while the second compares a variable with string (e.g. if(Test == 'Test') will return false if variable Test is undefined)